# Redirect the page with Height & width

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a doubt that i can redirect the page , but can i put height and width there

```
response.redirect("Mypage.aspx");
```

for eg

```
response.redirect("Mypage.aspx",height="300px",width="200px");
```

i am doing this in asp.net, c#

Comment: So what happened when you did your response.redirect with those parameters? Is it even a valid overload of the Redirect method ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open a page with this method, use javascript `window.open` instead.

```
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "", "window.open('Mypage.aspx','mywindow','menubar=1,resizable=1,width=300,height=200');", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

dude, you quite lost... I suggest you to understand the server side concept of web application first, otherwise the learning asp.net experience could be frustrating...

regarding your question, there is not such thing what you want to do, the display on the page is html format in the client side (applying style(for example) to html elements )

although you can map those html ui in the server side